# Паттерн ООП, ограничивающий количество экземпляров класса по атрибуту

Tags: ооп, многопоточность, шаблоны-проектирования

Как организовать невозможность в программе существования нескольких экземпляров одного класса с одинаковым значением определенного атрибута? 
Как называется такой паттерн ООП (если он есть)?
Пишу приложение на JAVA, многопоточное, но примеры интересны на различных языках программирования (естественно с ООП парадигмой).

Comment: Перегрузить оператор new и вставить туда соответствующую проверку.

Comment: @igumnov Хотел бы я посмотреть на это.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать Ну если внутрь тела new кроме размера подавать ссылку на глобальный объект который хранит информацию о созданных экземплярах остальных классов(и обновлять там же эту информацию), то теоретически это возможно. Хотя я такого никогда не делал, поэтому точно не могу сказать какие могут быть подводные камни.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать Так наверное можно и автоматическую велосипедную сборку мусора приделать при большом желании. 
P.S. Я имею в виду C++, а не Java тут конечно и под атрибутом понимаю просто значение члена класса.

Comment: @irockez, наверное проще всего сделать в объекте метод самодиагностики, который возвращает либо null либо this.

Т.е. создаете (или меняете атрибут) и тут же вызываете этот метод.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

В общем случае наиболее подходит под вашу задачу паттерн Factory. В частном случае, когда разрешен всего 1 объект это классический Singleton. Единственное, я бы не стал возлагать на паттерн задачу безопасности ибо что Singleton, что Factory ломаются на раз-два.

**Update**

Применительно к Java такой способ ведь действительно существует и часто используется в реальной жизни - например кэширование пула коннектов (например JDBC). Как известно, коннект ресурс достаточно дорогой и ценный и если по ходу пьесы коннект берется во многих местах имеет смысл организовать кэширование коннектов с ограничением количества оных.

Вполне аналогично также и ставится ограничение на количество окон в системе. Да в том же Android'е надысь писал такую штуку. Ставится корневой класс - прародителей всех Activity и вперед создавать списочек, контроль все как надо.

Так что надо попроще и без кошачьих завихрений, а то совсем ужо замутили головы `boost commiter`, перегрузка операторов...

P.S. Ну вы млин даёте :)

Answer (score 8):

- Эта задачу (если решать ее в общем виде) **очень сложно решить хорошо** в языках с `Garbage Collector'ами` в силу недетерминированности работы последних.

> - Под *хорошим* решением подразумевается что-то типа специальной фабрики `ObjectFactoryWithAttributeChecking`, в которой хранятся слабые ссылки на объекты выбранных типов, и при попытке создания нового объекта она проверяет, жив ли прошлый / прошлые или нет.
> - Понятно, что, в силу недетерминированности `GC` очень легко получить ситуацию, когда на объект уже никто не ссылается, но он еще не заколлекчен (и в этот момент фабрика `ObjectFactoryWithAttributeChecking` будет вести себя некорректно).

- Плохой подход - вводить такую же фабрику с явными методами `Create` и `Dispose` - решает задачу, но сводит на нет преимущества автоматической сборки мусора и **крайне неустойчив.**

> Если `calling site` в случае такого подхода забудет вызвать `Dispose`, то ваша фабрика моментально оказывается в неконсистентном состоянии.

- Если задача поставлена из соображений отладки, то самый верный путь решения заключается в инжектировании своего кода в аллокатор на низком уровне.

> `.NET`, например, допускает такие штуки для решения задач профайлинга, но, в случае выбора такого подхода каждый кейс нужно рассматривать индивидуально.

- В случае языков без сборки мусора (типа `C++`) вроде как можно реализовать решение на уровне собственного аллокатора, но сделать это **правильно для всех кейсов** крайне нетривиально. Такая задача должна быть по зубам разработчиками уровня `boost commiter,` да и то, наверняка, не всем.

---

##### Небольшой Update:

- Сейчас еще раз перечитал вопрос и, в принципе (если вас устроит такой подход), вы можете просто сделать *фабрику ленивых синглтонов* - т.е фабрику с методом `getObjectWithSomeConcreteAttribute`, которая будет создавать объект с таким атрибутом только один раз по его первому запросу.

> Создание объектов в обход фабрики в таком случае, разумеется, надо запретить.

- Другое дело, что это не слишком интересно, если сравнивать с задачей, решения для которой я предлагаю выше :)

Comment: Хмм... если фабрика `ObjectFactoryWithAttributeChecking` будет держать ссылки на объекты, то каким образом они попадут под каток сборщика мусора? Или я чего-то не догнал?

Comment: @Barmaley Ну, слабые ссылки-то то не влияют на процесс сборки мусора.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать а что мешает держать нормальные ссылки?

Comment: @Barmaley

- Смотрите, я предложил решения для двух схожих задач, одна из которых на порядок сложнее.

- **Простая задача:** найти удобный способ обращения к объекту (или нескольким объектам), время жизни которого совпадает с временем работы приложения при условии, что инстанс у объекта может быть только один.

- Эта задача решается тем, что написано у вас или во второй части моего ответа - фабрикой, которая создает объекты и не отпускает ссылки на них.

Comment: - **Сложная задача:** сделать тоже самое, но так, чтобы, скажем, можно было создать не более пяти инстансов одного и того же объекта, и чтобы их время жизни определялось исключительно по наличию ссылок на них и без применения паттерна `Disposable.`

- То есть, пока до 5 объектов можно достучаться, не позволять создавать еще один. Так вот, в контексте этой задачи я сделал вывод, что правильного поведения не достичь без инжекта в аллокатор и прочих приятнейших вещей.

- Понятно, что использование обычных (не слабых) ссылок в этом кейсе бессмысленно.

Answer (score 2):

Есть такой вариант решения "проблемы", недостатки такого подхода очевидны, хотя вариант имеет право на жизнь (видел в нескольких enterprise продуктах):

```
public enum TestEnum {

    INTEGER {
        @Override
        public void doAction(Object arg) {
            if (arg instanceof Integer) {
                System.out.println("int - " + arg);
            }
        }
    },
    STRING {
        @Override
        public void doAction(Object arg) {
            if (arg instanceof String) {
                System.out.println("str - " + arg);
            }
        }
    },

    BOOLEAN {
        @Override
        public void doAction(Object arg) {
            if (arg instanceof Boolean) {
                System.out.println("bool - " + arg);
            }
        }
    };

    public abstract void doAction(Object arg);

    public static void applyAction(Object arg) {
        System.out.println("Handling: '" + arg + "'");
        for (TestEnum e : values()) {
            e.doAction(arg);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<Object> objects = new LinkedList<Object>();
        objects.add("ab");
        objects.add(Integer.valueOf(1));
        objects.add("cd");
        objects.add(Integer.valueOf(2));
        objects.add(Boolean.valueOf(true));
        objects.add(Integer.valueOf(3));
        objects.add("ef");

        for (Object object : objects) {
            TestEnum.applyAction(object);
        }

    }

}
```